# nonlinear ODEs optimization with leastsq

Tags: optimization, ode, least-squares, scilab

[UPDATED] I'm working on a nonlinear ODEs system optimization and fitting it to experimental data. I have a system of 5 model ODEs which must be optimized by 17 parameters. My approach is to calculate the differences between solved ODEs and experimental data - function Differences, then use leastsq solver to minimize diferences and find the optimal parameters, as below code:

```
//RHSs of ODEs to be fitted:

function dx=model3(t,x,Kap,Ksa,Ko,Ks,Kia,Kis,p_Amax,q_Amax,qm,q_Smax,Yas,Yoa,Yxa,Yem,Yos,Yxsof,H)
    X=x(1);
    S=x(2);
    A=x(3);
    DO=x(4);
    V=x(5);`
    
    qs=((q_Smax*S/(S+Ks))*Kia/(Kia+A));
    qsof=(p_Amax*qs/(qs+Kap));
    qsox=(qs-qsof)*DO/(DO+Ko);
    qsa=(q_Amax*A/(A+Ksa))*(Kis/(qs+Kis));
    pa=qsof*Yas;
    qa=pa-qsa;
    qo=(qsox-qm)*Yos+qsa*Yoa;
    u=(qsox-qm)*Yem+qsof*Yxsof+qsa*Yxa;
    
    dx(1)=u*X-F*X/V;
    dx(2)=(F*(Sf-S)/V)-qs*X;
    dx(3)=qsa*X-(F*A/V);
    dx(4)=200*(100-DO)-qo*X*H;
    dx(5)=F;
endfunction

//experimental data:
//Dat=fscanfMat('dane_exper_III_etap.txt');

Dat = [
0   30  1.4 24.1    99  6884.754
1   35  0.2 23.2    89  6959.754
2   40  0.1 21.6    80  7034.754
3   52  0.1 19.5    67  7109.754
4   61  0.1 18.7    70  7184.754
5   66  0.1 16.4    79  7259.754
6   71  0.1 15      94  7334.754
7   74  0   14.3    100 7409.754
8   76  0   13.8    100 7484.754
9   78  0   13.4    100 7559.754
9.5 79  0   13.2    100 7597.254
10  79  0   13.5    100 7634.754]

t=Dat(:,1);
x_exp(:,1)=Dat(:,2);
x_exp(:,2)=Dat(:,3);
x_exp(:,3)=Dat(:,4);
x_exp(:,4)=Dat(:,5);
x_exp(:,5)=Dat(:,6);

global MYDATA;
MYDATA.t=t;
MYDATA.x_exp=x_exp;
MYDATA.funeval=0;


//calculating differences between calculated values and experimental data:

function f=Differences(k)
    global MYDATA
    t=MYDATA.t;
    x_exp=MYDATA.x_exp;
    Kap=k(1); //g/L
    Ksa=k(2); //g/L
    Ko=k(3); //g/L
    Ks=k(4); //g/L
    Kia=k(5); //g/L
    Kis=k(6); //g/L
    p_Amax=k(7); //g/(g*h)
    q_Amax=k(8); //g/(g*h)
    qm=k(9);
    q_Smax=k(10);
    Yas=k(11); //g/g
    Yoa=k(12);
    Yxa=k(13);
    Yem=k(14);
    Yos=k(15);
    Yxsof=k(16);
    H=k(17);
    x0=x_exp(1,:);
    t0=0;
    F=75;
    Sf=500;
    %ODEOPTIONS=[1,0,0,%inf,0,2,10000,12,5,0,-1,-1]
    x_calc=ode('rk',x0',t0,t,list(model3,Kap,Ksa,Ko,Ks,Kia,Kis,p_Amax,q_Amax,qm,q_Smax,Yas,Yoa,Yxa,Yem,Yos,Yxsof,H));
    diffmat=x_calc'-x_exp;
    //column vector of differences (concatenates 4 columns of the difference matrix)
    f=diffmat(:);
    MYDATA.funeval=MYDATA.funeval+1;
endfunction

// Initial guess
Kap=0.3; //g/L
Ksa=0.05; //g/L
Ko=0.1; //g/L
Ks=0.5; //g/L
Kia=0.5; //g/L
Kis=0.05; //g/L
p_Amax=0.4; //g/(g*h)
q_Amax=0.8; //g/(g*h)
qm=0.2;
q_Smax=0.6;
Yas=0.5; //g/g
Yoa=0.5;
Yxa=0.5;
Yem=0.5;
Yos=1.5;
Yxsof=0.22;
H=1000;

y0=[Kap;Ksa;Ko;Ks;Kia;Kis;p_Amax;q_Amax;qm;q_Smax;Yas;Yoa;Yxa;Yem;Yos;Yxsof;H];

yinf=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100];

ysup=[%inf,%inf,%inf,%inf,%inf,%inf,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,10000];

[fopt,xopt,gopt]=leastsq(Differences,'b',yinf,ysup,y0);
```

Now result is:

```
  0.2994018
   0.0508325
   0.0999987
   0.4994088
   0.5081272
   0.
   0.4004560
   0.7050746
   0.2774195
   0.6068328
   0.5
   0.4926150
   0.4053860
   0.5255006
   1.5018725
   0.2193901
   1000.0000

   33591.642
```

Running this script causes such an error:

```
lsoda--  caution... t (=r1) and h (=r2) are
     such that t + h = t at next step
      (h = pas). integration continues
      where r1 is :   0.5658105345269D+01   and r2 :   0.1884898700920D-17       
lsoda--  previous message precedent given i1 times
     will no more be repeated
      where i1 is :         10                                                   
lsoda--  at t (=r1), mxstep (=i1) steps   
needed before reaching tout
      where i1 is :     500000                                                   
      where r1 is :   0.5658105345270D+01                                        
Excessive work done on this call (perhaps wrong jacobian type).
at line    27 of function Differences
```

I understand that problem is on ODEs solving step. Thus, I have tried changing the mxstep, as also solving method type to 'adams','rk', and 'stiff' - none of this solved the problem. Using 'fix' method in ode I get this error:

```
ode: rksimp exit with state 3.
```

Please advise how to solve this?

P.S. Experimental data in file 'dane_exper_III_etap.txt':

```
0   30  1.4 24.1    99  6884.754
1   35  0.2 23.2    89  6959.754
2   40  0.1 21.6    80  7034.754
3   52  0.1 19.5    67  7109.754
4   61  0.1 18.7    70  7184.754
5   66  0.1 16.4    79  7259.754
6   71  0.1 15      94  7334.754
7   74  0   14.3    100 7409.754
8   76  0   13.8    100 7484.754
9   78  0   13.4    100 7559.754
9.5 79  0   13.2    100 7597.254
10  79  0   13.5    100 7634.754
```

Comment: try forcing "stiff" method. Besides this, it is highly probable that leastsq makes calls with non-physical values of the prameters. Add constraints in the leastsq call.

Comment: Have added constraints in leastsq and tried also "stiff" method - no results, but gives diferent error:
```
lsode--  at t (=r1) with step h (=r2), 
     corrector does not converge 
      with abs(h) = hmin   
      where r1 is :   0.1366396046954D+01   and r2 :   0.6917767912662D-16       
Repeated convergence failures (perhaps bad jacobian supplied or wrong choice of jacobian type or tolerances)
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the new code including constrains and actual Data assignment to `Dat` ?

Comment: Please find updates above

Comment: I made  the modification in the code (so that one can directly execute the script in Scilab. You should display the value of the parameters in the residual function, in order to understand if the ode solver fails because of weird values. It could help to add tighter bounds.

Comment: Some parameters of your model are yields aren't they  ? Maybe could you take more sensible upper bounds...

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have tightened upper bounds of constraints and used "rk" and "stiff" method what gave result but fopt value is big, so solution is not accurate. I consider that guess values of parameters can be chosen better, because changing them gives different solutions. Could you suggest some algorithm of calculation of the initial values?

Comment: Can you update the bounds in the code above  ? Please make sure that the whole code runs after copy/paste.

Comment: Code is updated, works fine for me but needs improvement.

Comment: The code does not run (I copy/pasted the above): at line    92 of function leastsq ( /Applications/scilab-6.1.1.app/Contents/share/scilab/modules/optimization/macros/leastsq.sci line 104 )
at line   116 of executed file /Users/mottelet/so.sce

**optim: Bounds and initial guess are incompatible.**

Comment: Sorry, now should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scilab `leastsq` (based on `optim`) is very poor and doesn't have global convergence properties, unlike `ipopt` which is available as an atoms module. Install it like  this:

```
--> atomsInstall sci_ipopt
```

I have modified your script in the following way

1. keep classical use of ode for this kind of biological kinetics, i.e. "stiff" (which uses BDF method). The Runge-Kutta you were using is very poor as it is an explicit method only for gentle ODEs.
2. use `ipopt` instead of `leastsq`
3. use a try/catch/end block around the computation of the residual in order to catch failing calls to the ode solver.
4. use some weight for the residual. You should play with it in order to improve the fit
5. use a strictly positive lower bound instead of 0, as very low value of some parameters make the ode solver fail.
6. add a drawing callback that also saves current value of parameters in case where you stop the optimization with ctrl-C.

```
//RHSs of ODEs to be fitted:

function dx=model3(t,x,Kap,Ksa,Ko,Ks,Kia,Kis,p_Amax,q_Amax,qm,q_Smax,Yas,Yoa,Yxa,Yem,Yos,Yxsof,H)
    X=x(1);
    S=x(2);
    A=x(3);
    DO=x(4);
    V=x(5);
    
    qs=((q_Smax*S/(S+Ks))*Kia/(Kia+A));
    qsof=(p_Amax*qs/(qs+Kap));
    qsox=(qs-qsof)*DO/(DO+Ko);
    qsa=(q_Amax*A/(A+Ksa))*(Kis/(qs+Kis));
    pa=qsof*Yas;
    qa=pa-qsa;
    qo=(qsox-qm)*Yos+qsa*Yoa;
    u=(qsox-qm)*Yem+qsof*Yxsof+qsa*Yxa;
    
    dx(1)=u*X-F*X/V;
    dx(2)=(F*(Sf-S)/V)-qs*X;
    dx(3)=qsa*X-(F*A/V);
    dx(4)=200*(100-DO)-qo*X*H;
    dx(5)=F;
endfunction


//calculating differences between calculated values and experimental data:

function [f,x_calc]=Differences(k, t, x_exp)
    Kap=k(1); //g/L
    Ksa=k(2); //g/L
    Ko=k(3); //g/L
    Ks=k(4); //g/L
    Kia=k(5); //g/L
    Kis=k(6); //g/L
    p_Amax=k(7); //g/(g*h)
    q_Amax=k(8); //g/(g*h)
    qm=k(9);
    q_Smax=k(10);
    Yas=k(11); //g/g
    Yoa=k(12);
    Yxa=k(13);
    Yem=k(14);
    Yos=k(15);
    Yxsof=k(16);
    H=k(17);
    x0=x_exp(1,:);
    t0=0;
    F=75;
    Sf=500;
    [x_calc]=ode("stiff",x0',t0,t,list(model3,Kap,Ksa,Ko,Ks,Kia,Kis,p_Amax,q_Amax,qm,q_Smax,Yas,Yoa,Yxa,Yem,Yos,Yxsof,H));
    diffmat=(x_calc'-x_exp)*residual_weight;
    //column vector of differences (concatenates 4 columns of the difference matrix)
    f=diffmat(:);
    MYDATA.funeval=MYDATA.funeval+1;
endfunction

function [f,g]=normdiff2(k,new_k,t,x_exp)
    try
        res = Differences(k,t,x_exp)
        if  argn(1) == 2
            JacRes = numderivative(list(Differences,t,x_exp),k)
            g = 2*JacRes'*res;
        end
        f = sum(res.*res)
    catch
        f=%inf;
        g=%inf*ones(k);
    end
endfunction

function out=callback(param)
    global MYDATA
    if isfield(param,"x")
        k = param.x;
        MYDATA.k = k;
        [f,x_calc]=Differences(k,t,x_exp)
        plot_weight = diag(1./max(x_exp,'r'));
        drawlater
        clf
        plot(t,x_exp*plot_weight,'-o')
        plot(t,x_calc'*plot_weight,'-x')
        legend X S A DO X
        drawnow
    end
    out = %t;
endfunction

//experimental data:
//Dat=fscanfMat('dane_exper_III_etap.txt');

Dat = [
0   30  1.4 24.1    99  6884.754
1   35  0.2 23.2    89  6959.754
2   40  0.1 21.6    80  7034.754
3   52  0.1 19.5    67  7109.754
4   61  0.1 18.7    70  7184.754
5   66  0.1 16.4    79  7259.754
6   71  0.1 15      94  7334.754
7   74  0   14.3    100 7409.754
8   76  0   13.8    100 7484.754
9   78  0   13.4    100 7559.754
9.5 79  0   13.2    100 7597.254
10  79  0   13.5    100 7634.754]

t=Dat(:,1);
x_exp(:,1)=Dat(:,2);
x_exp(:,2)=Dat(:,3);
x_exp(:,3)=Dat(:,4);
x_exp(:,4)=Dat(:,5);
x_exp(:,5)=Dat(:,6);

global MYDATA;
MYDATA.funeval=0;

// Initial guess
Kap=0.3; //g/L
Ksa=0.05; //g/L
Ko=0.1; //g/L
Ks=0.5; //g/L
Kia=0.5; //g/L
Kis=0.05; //g/L
p_Amax=0.4; //g/(g*h)
q_Amax=0.8; //g/(g*h)
qm=0.2;
q_Smax=0.6;
Yas=0.5; //g/g
Yoa=0.5;
Yxa=0.5;
Yem=0.5;
Yos=1.5;
Yxsof=0.22;
H=100;

k0 = [Kap;Ksa;Ko;Ks;Kia;Kis;p_Amax;q_Amax;qm;q_Smax;Yas;Yoa;Yxa;Yem;Yos;Yxsof;H];

residual_weight = diag(1./[79,1.4, 24.1, 100, 7634.754]);

BIG = 1000;
SMALL = 1e-3;
problem = struct();
problem.f = list(normdiff2,t,x_exp);
problem.x0 = k0;
problem.x_lower = [SMALL*ones(16,1);100];
problem.x_upper = [BIG,BIG,BIG,BIG,BIG,BIG,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,10000]';
problem.int_cb = callback;
problem.params = struct("max_iter",200);
//
k = ipopt(problem)
```

Here is a plot of the results after 100 iterations (you can change the value in the ipopt options). However, don't expect normal termination as

1. it is almost sure that your parameter set is not identifiable
2. finite difference gradient with ODEs is very innacurate.

Hope it will help you a little bit...
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It took a while to understand the code and meet ipopt toolbox (by the way, it is nice to meet the author of this module). I have simplifyed a little bit my model ODEs and result is satisfying. Once again thanks!

Comment: Great ! Just for information, what kind of model is it ?

Comment: Diauxic bacteria growth model using Monod kinetics.